# How to use local-storage from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I wish to send/receive data from the local storage. For eg: If I have an object named 'names', how do I process it?

Comment: possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: There are tons of tutorials available for the [Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage_API)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow @Gibberish!

As provided by @Andreas, you can visit the link. But, I would like to give you a kickstart

**To receive data from localStorage**

```
const names = localStorage.getItem('names'); //names will be a String. Don't forget to parse it!
```

**To send data to localStorage**

```
localStorage.setItem('names', JSON.stringify(names))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a standard API for using the local storage and has simple usage, ex:
wanna set a value you would call 
`localStorage.setItem(k, v)`
and when getting item from storage you would call
`localStorage.getItem(k)`
where k is short for key and v for value

You can read more here [how to use local storage](http://%20https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-use-local-storage-with-javascript/)